# Lookup several keywords in a column, if found, return 4 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I've got two databases, one with 11,000 entries, and another that I've narrowed down to around 600. They are databases with Company name, and contact information for people at that company. So `column A - Company Name. Column B - last name, column C - first name, column D - position, and column E - email address`. What I'd like to do is search column D - position for several keywords - vice, benefit, resource, and if found, return the four columns - last name, first name, position and email address. So for company name X, we might have 10 contact names, and a couple may have contact info for people that fall into those keywords. I'd like to return those specific people.

I've managed to get the formatting between the company names normalized between the two lists, using brute force, and some index matching formulas (that was fun!), so those are the same, and I could probably do something like add 5 or 6 rows after each unique company name to accommodate the potential number of contacts we might have for each company, but I have no idea how to return multiple specific cells for a keyword search.

I think something like this might work -

```
=index(columntoreturn, small(if(isnumber(search(keywords, columntosearch)), match(row(column), row(column))), rows(array)))
```

But that will only return an individual cell, rather than the four I would need.

Here's an example of the two databases I'm working with.

[image: Smaller database example]

[image: Larger database example]

Comment: Use Advanced Filter.

Comment: Apologies Scott, I've removed the adjunct question, and the post on the other site, didn't mean to break the rules!

Comment: As I stated in my first comment, Advanced Filter is designed for this.  You can put code to automatically do it based on certain cells on the page changing values.  A formula is not ideal in that it would require it to be an array formula and the more array formulas and the larger the dataset would bog down the calc times. See [here for an example](https://www.contextures.com/exceladvancedfiltervba.html) on how to set up advanced filter using vba.

Comment: Oh my god I didn't even see that! Geeze I feel like an idiot, again, apologies Scott! Feel like I've caused you some headaches this morning. Thank you for taking the time to explain all that, I'll take a crack at it now, thank you again.

Comment: That worked perfectly Scott, how do I close the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you asked the same have been closed as answered thorugh comment behalf of @Scott Craner

Answer

As I stated in my first comment, Advanced Filter is designed for this. You can put code to automatically do it based on certain cells on the page changing values. A formula is not ideal in that it would require it to be an array formula and the more array formulas and the larger the dataset would bog down the calc times. See [here for an example](https://www.contextures.com/exceladvancedfiltervba.html) on how to set up advanced filter using vba.